# Rails 5.2.0 —— How to delete sub values of cookies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, cookies, substring

I have a `cookies.permanent[:liked]`:

```
cookies.permanent[:liked] = 'liked1#liked2#'
```

I removed `liked1#`:

```
cookies.permanent[:liked].slice! `liked1#`
```

I get `cookies.permanent[:liked]`:

```
'liked2#'
```

Next, I removed `'liked2#'`:

```
cookies.permanent[:liked].slice! `liked2#`
```

and I thought I would get '', but I got:

```
'liked1#'
```

And I printed `cookies.permanent[:liked]`, I got `'liked1#liked2#'`!

I just want to delete a substring of cookies value, but I find it still can be read.

So, how to do that? Note, I must use `permanent`.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I find I can do this by this:

```
temp = cookies.permanent[:liked]
wanted_deleted = 'liked1#'
temp.slice! wanted_deleted
cookies.permanent[:liked] = temp
```

Now, value of `cookies.permanent[:liked]` is 'liked2#'

There has more efficient ways?